# xcode showing errors continously but can compile when using a pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have developped my own cocoapod to gather all the code I use in my apps. But since I have included my Pod (inserting `pod 'MadJohTools` in my `PodFile` and running `pod install`), xcode keeps showing me 100+ errors whereas I can compile/run/archive without any problem.

The errors mainly come from `Class Extensions` that are in my pod. I can't find a way to get rid of these error (cleaning, building, restarting xcode or the mac...) The errors always come back after a few seconds.

Any tip is welcome ! Thanks

PS: The `extensions` added are simple getters/setters or methods, nothing complex.

EDIT: Here is an example:

Code in my pod:

```
public extension UIView
{
    public var x: CGFloat 
    {
        get 
        {
            return self.frame.origin.x
        }
        set
        {
            self.frame.origin.x = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting using `myView.x = 0` is `Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'x'`

Comment: I think an error output sample would be helpful Dliix :)

Comment: Do your pod and project have the same swift version?

Comment: @Chris I added an example in the original post. Thanks for taking the time to have a look at it.

Comment: @Axel, Yes, they are both done in swift3.